# web server requirement for below architecture

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, web-applications

[[image: [1]]

This is AWS 3 tier web application architecture. If we host static contents in S3, then why we require web server???

May anyone give me sample application which have sample contents for all section like S3, web-server, app server and db.

Comment: I would suggest that you ask that question of the consultants who gave you this diagram. It's probably not how I would structure a deployment, but they may have reasons for it.

Answer (score 0):

It is used for serving Static assets such as videos, PDFs, Javascript, CSS and image files, Once uploaded your application can reference its assets by copying their public URLs (such as http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname/filename) and pasting them directly into your app’s views or HTML files. These files will now be served directly from S3, freeing up your application to serve only dynamic requests.

[Web Application Hosting Architecture](https://media.amazonwebservices.com/architecturecenter/AWS_ac_ra_web_01.pdf)

> Resources and static content used by the web application are stored on
>   Amazon Simple Storage Service(S3) a highly durable storage
>   infrastructure designed for mission-critical and primary data storage.

Comment: If you look at the diagram, you'll see that static assets are delivered via CloudFront, so there's no need for a web-server. Moreover, the OP already knows that assets can be served directly from S3.